# jQuery on click works when executed in console but not when page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use the following jquery in my page.

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
j(document).ready(function(){
    console.log(j("#label_19"));
    j("#label_19").on("click",function(){
        alert("Clicked");
    });
});
```

When document loads, the element (it's a checkbox) appears in the console. But when I click the checkbox, the alert is **not thrown**. But when I copy the same code (as below)

```
    j("#label_19").on("click",function(){
        alert("Clicked");
    });
```

in console panel and press run. Now when I click the checkbox, the alert **is thrown**. What could be the issue in this case?

#### Updated:

What I observe in console is:

```
Object[input#label_19.document_label attribute value = "Check-In"]
```

The HTML markup is

```
<input id="label_19" class="document_label" type="checkbox" value="Check-In" name="label[19]">
```

Comment: What does the markup look like? Also, when saying "it shows in the console" it's best to actually **show** what you're seeing in the console, in case you're misinterpreting it.

Comment: @Saravanan where do you include your js in head or end of the body

Comment: @RohitAgrawal: Doesn't really matter given that he's using `ready`.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy: If he weren't, he wouldn't be seeing the `console.log` statement running at all. 'tis an odd one, this, but more context will probably make it clear.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder i know just wanted to know that if he is doing in the end he actually need not to use ready

Comment: @RohitAgrawal: Indeed. I'm not a fan of `ready`. :-) (Not if you control where the `script` tags go.)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kTKyC/ works for me -- is there anything different with your code?

Comment: looks at event delegation!!! seems like `label_19` is created dynamically

Comment: @Saravanan you can re-factor your code by using classic enclosure of anonymous function and passing jQuery as a argument to prevent the conflict

Comment: @ArunPJohny: probably not the issue -- the `console.log` call apparently shows the element.

Comment: the best way is to share the code with us to look deeper

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy: I'm not sure I trust the claim that the element is showing up in the console. *Something* is showing there, but I'm not at all sure I believe it's really a jQuery set containing that element, not if the next line isn't working.

Comment: anyway can you try `j(document).on("click", "#label_19", function () {
    alert("Clicked");
});`

Comment: also whether there are multiple elements with the same id?

Comment: Regarding your edit, the id in the markup doesn't match the id in your JS, so I don't see how your code could work in the console or in a script on the page.

Comment: The ID in the HTML and in the javascript don't match

Comment: Based on the info provided (and a corrected mismatch in the id), the following fiddle works: http://jsfiddle.net/494wm/  The question is, how does your scenario differ from the test case..?  It might be worthwhile stripping down your code to just this and adding things back until it breaks.

Comment: ID mismatch is my typo in this question, corrected now.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your very quick responses. The problem was, manipulation of that specific DOM was handled by many listeners at various times. So the listener in my question doesn't work. The answer by @T.J.Crowder opened a door with possibility.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only explanation that fits the facts you've presented is that there is code running after your `ready` callback but before you click the element that *replaces* the element in question. Some kind of ajax callback or similar.

You'll need to look through your code to find the place where that's happening. Things to look for are any `html` calls on elements that contain the `#label_19` element, or (if there's a mix of jQuery and non-jQuery code) assignments to `innerHTML`.

You can use event delegation to solve this, which may or may not be the best answer depending on what your code is doing. That looks like this:

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
j(document).ready(function(){
    console.log(j("#label_19"));
    j(document).on("click", "#label_19", function(){ // This is the changed line
        alert("Clicked");
    });
});
```

There, instead of hooking `click` on the actual element, we're hooking it on `document` but then asking jQuery to only tell us about clicks that pass through elements matching the selector we give it as they bubble. That way, the fact that something is destroying and recreating the `#label_19` element doesn't matter, because we're not hooking a handler on that element. We're hooking the handler on `document` and checking, when the event occurs, if it passed through something that matches that selector.

But I wouldn't just blindly use event delegation, I'd find out what's really happening with that element.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it not only clears my issue. I had a new thing to learn today(your desscription makes it).

Comment: Thanks for the help @T.J.Crowder

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing the rest of your code—including HTML and related DOM elements—have you considered using `j(window).load()` instead of `j(document).ready()`

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
j(window).load(function(){
    console.log(j("#label_19"));
    j("#label_19").on("click",function(){
        alert("Clicked");
    });
});
```

As explained [here](http://4loc.wordpress.com/2009/04/28/documentready-vs-windowload/):

> The window load event executes a bit later when the complete page is fully loaded, including all frames, objects and images. Therefore functions which concern images or other page contents should be placed in the load event for the window or the content tag itself.

Comment: That just moves the goal line in whatever race is taking place; what's needed is to remove the race condition entirely. *(Not my dv)*

Comment: Well your solutions works for me @JakeGould, you have my up vote

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, it got resolved after i wrapped it in a window.load

```
(function ($) {
    $(window).on('load', function () {
        //MY click calls inside here
    });    
})(jQuery);
```

Hope it helps!